# DEM gap filling with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a DEM, geo tif, Float32 whith some gaps.
Pixel value relative to the gaps is indicated in the metadata as -9999, but if I click on these pixel with the identify value tool -9999.96 is shown.
I tried to fill these gaps whith the tool raster > analysis > fill no data, but it doesn't produce any result.

Comment: Is there any reason you think those pixels are nodata?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea

Comment: Second question (sorry...) These gap-looking pixels are all `-9999.96`? (Changing value to `-9999.00` may solve this issue).

Comment: Maybe, how to do this?

Comment: How about the Raster Calculator? For instance `(DEM@1 != -9999.96) * DEM@1 + (DEM@1 = -9999.96) * (-9999.00)`